# How to avoid Internal_Function by TO_CHAR IN Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, to-char

I'm using Oracle 12C and I have the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        t.tablea
    WHERE
        name = 'FIS'
) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        t.tableb
    WHERE
        enabled = 1
) B ON b.id = a.id
       AND TO_CHAR(b.createdate, 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi') = TO_CHAR(a.createdate, 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi')
```

Both a and b createdate are timestamp datatype.

Optimizer return an internal_function at TO_CHAR(b.createdate, 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi') = TO_CHAR(a.createdate, 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi') in Execution Plan

If I compare like this: 'AND b.createdate = a.createdate', It will lost 1000 rows that look like this '11-JUN-18 04.48.34.269928000 PM'. And If I change 269928000 to 269000000 It will work

Now, I don't want to using to_char to avoid internal_function(must create Function-based-Index)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why are you surprised to see the function `to_char()` in your execution plan? You explicitly use it in your query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't surprised, I just wanna avoid it to avoid create Function-based-Index

Comment: What's the problem with the function based index?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My boss never agree with function based index, sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I compare like this: `AND b.createdate = a.createdate`, It will lost 1000 rows that look like this `11-JUN-18 04.48.34.269928000 PM`. And If I change `269928000` to `269000000` It will work

Your values appear to have a fractional seconds component and would have the `TIMESTAMP` data type. If so, you can use `TRUNC( timestamp_value, 'MI' )` to truncate to the nearest minute.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   t.tablea a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t.tableb b
       ON (   a.createdate >= TRUNC( b.createdate, 'MI' )
          AND a.createdate <  TRUNC( b.createdate, 'MI' ) + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
          AND a.id         =  b.id
          AND b.enabled    =  1
          )
WHERE  a.name = 'FIS'
```

This will remove the need to apply a function to one of the two tables (`a.createdate` in this case but you could swap them).

Answer (score 2):

I don't even see the need for the subqueries:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM t.tablea a
LEFT JOIN t.tableb b
    ON a.id = b.id AND
       TRUNC(b.createdate, 'MI') = TRUNC(a.createdate, 'MI') AND
       b.enabled = 1
WHERE
    a.name = 'FIS'
```

Comment: This will also join year 2019 with year 1919 or 2119 (if such data exists in table). I would prefer `TRUNC(b.createdate, 'MI') = TRUNC(a.createdate, 'MI')`. Performance wise it should be as fast (or as slow) as your approach.

Comment: @Wern Well it's a good thing 2119 hasn't happened yet, isn't it?

Comment: Most likely there is no data for 2119 but 1919 could be.